# refreshing DIV or ID without reloading whole page

Tags: javascript

I am cracking my head over this now for two days... Frustrating. I have a html page which contains divs who get their value from a JS on the page. I am running a loop to refresh them but: Nothing happens. So I am a JS beginner but: Console doesn't give me an error. jsFiddle says my loop code is ok... WHAT AM I MISSING????

```js
var delay = 1000;

function loop() {

 $.get("http://www.starhit1fm.com/Friday.html")
    .done(function(r) {
      var newDom = $(r);
      $('#imgContainer').replaceWith($('#imgContainer', newDom));
      $('#status').replaceWith($('#status', newDom));
      $('#showon').replaceWith($('#pshowon', newDom));
    });


  if (time >= 0 && time <= 4) {
    imgElement.src = "https://www.starhit1fm.com/images/covers/nonstop1.jpg";
    imgEeight = 70;
    imgElement.width = 70;
    // the image to a container div
    var container = document.getElementById("imageContainer");
    container.appendChild(imgElement);
    var showstatus = "- - - - -&nbsp;&nbsp;Y O U&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;A R E&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;L I S T E N I N G&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;T O&nbsp;&nbsp;- - - - -";
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = showstatus;
    var actshow = "&nbsp;Music Non Stop<br>&nbsp;We get you through the night!"
    document.getElementById("showon").innerHTML = actshow;
  }
}
setInterval(loop, delay);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div align="center">
  <table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="center">
        <font face="Verdana" size="3" color="#FF0000"><b><span class="blinking" id="status"></span></b></font>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id="time"></div>
        <div id="imageContainer"></div>
      </td>
      <td valign="middle">
        <div>
          <span style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 20px;">
         <b> <span id="showon"></span></b>
          </span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

This code is supposed to refresh DIV tags or IDs on my html page. I just don't know anymore where my problem is.... The code is on the same page where the JS is with the if else loops.
You can check the page at [www.starhit1fm.com/Friday.html](http://www.starhit1fm.com/Friday.html)

Comment: You're assigning to the same elements in the AJAX callback and the `if (time >= 0 && time <= 4)` code.

Comment: I'm not able to load that URL.

Comment: What is determining the change in `time`?  I'm trying to reproduce this using your code, but no idea where `time` is coming from

Comment: @KeithRusso 
' var imgElement = document.createElement("img");
     var timeInMyTimeZone = moment.tz("America/Regina");
     var time = timeInMyTimeZone.hour();

     if (time >= 0 && time <= 4) {
        imgElement.src = "https://www.starhit1fm.com/images/covers/nonstop1.jpg";
        imgEeight = 70;
        imgElement.width = 70;
        // the image to a container div
       '

Comment: @Barmar ?Why? I can access that URL from all devices.

Comment: Can you update this to a [mcve] as a [runnable code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/328193) which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Looks like an issue with my ISP, I can get to it from another server.

Comment: The HTML contains `id="imageContainer"`, but the JavaScript uses `$("#imgContainer")`. Do you see the difference?

Comment: @Barmar Yes I just corrected it but still it should refresh the other ones like status and showon. They are correct. But it doesn't refresh at all

Comment: @AndYman: Are there any errors on the browser's console?  Are you running this code on the same domain as `www.starhit1fm.com`?  When I test this I get CORS errors.

Comment: Another typo: `#pshowon` should be `#showon`

Comment: @Barmar I think we are getting somewhere. So now it refreshes, The picture shows but the text is just like flashing and disappears

Comment: @David yes its in the same domain, in fact the same folder

Comment: @AndYman: How specifically is this failing then?  In your browser's debugging tools, on the Network tab, is the AJAX request being made at the expected intervals?  What is the server's response?  When you step through the code with your browser's script debugger, which specific operation first produces an unexpected result?

Comment: I suppose the real question here is if you are (assumingly, based on your comment about being on the same site and in the same folder) this site's developer and have access to the server and it's directories, why are you making ajax calls to your own server to get HTML?  There are much better tools and methods available other than using ajax to get a snippet of HTML you've already written on the same site and manipulate it on another page.

Comment: You're refreshing from the same static HTML page that you loaded initially. Why do you expect the content to change?

Comment: It seems like all you really need are the `if` statements that change the contents based on the time, you don't need to refresh from the file.

Comment: @Barmar yes, but i want them to update automatically if someone is on the page and the show changes depending on the time

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. Do you mean the HTML page might change and you want them to pick up those changes without reloading?

Comment: You should put the stuff that modifies the page based on the time in the `.done()` function, so it runs AFTER you reload those DIVs from the server.

Answer (score 0):

The console shows:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.starhit1fm.com/Friday.html'
> was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet
> 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arimo:400,700,400italic,700italic'.
> This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

So the problem is you need change

```
$.get("http://www.starhit1fm.com/Friday.html")
```

to

```
$.get("https://www.starhit1fm.com/Friday.html")
```

Comment: The OP isn't getting that error, so I think there's more to the problem than this.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is asynchronous, so your code that updates the DIVs based on the time is running before the AJAX completes. Then the `.done()` function overwrites them with the empty DIVs from the server.

You should move that code into the `.done()` function, so you first refresh from the server, then modify it based on the time.

You should also update the `time` variable each time the loop runs, so the content changes when the time of day changes.

```js
var delay = 1000;

function loop() {
  var timeInMyTimeZone = moment.tz("America/Regina");
  var time = timeInMyTimeZone.hour();

  $.get("http://www.starhit1fm.com/Friday.html")
    .done(function(r) {
      var newDom = $(r);
      $('#imageContainer').replaceWith($('#imgageContainer', newDom));
      $('#status').replaceWith($('#status', newDom));
      $('#showon').replaceWith($('#showon', newDom));
      if (time >= 0 && time <= 4) {
        imgElement.src = "https://www.starhit1fm.com/images/covers/nonstop1.jpg";
        imgEeight = 70;
        imgElement.width = 70;
        // the image to a container div
        var container = document.getElementById("imageContainer");
        container.appendChild(imgElement);
        var showstatus = "- - - - -&nbsp;&nbsp;Y O U&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;A R E&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;L I S T E N I N G&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;T O&nbsp;&nbsp;- - - - -";
        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = showstatus;
        var actshow = "&nbsp;Music Non Stop<br>&nbsp;We get you through the night!"
        document.getElementById("showon").innerHTML = actshow;
      }
    });
}
setInterval(loop, delay);
```

Comment: Well its showing now the content, its not flickeirng but that's because its not loading...